# What are the content of backup generated using Android system recovery?

Tags: backup, recovery-mode

I have an old Android Lollipop phone stuck on boot loop. I backed it up using recovery to my SD card.

What are the files included in that backup? Does it contain my application and its data, or it only has media files?

Comment: Which recovery did you use? What's the backup file name? How big it is? Did you open the file?

Comment: backup generates 6 files and total size is about 11 gb, backup files name are like "userdata_20151001_000800" and i am using stock recovery which come with old android lollipop devices.